# R: Capture output of regression in string

Tags: r

I am trying to capture the summary of regression in a string. I am trying the following:

```
data(iris)
reg <- lm( Sepal.Length ~ Species, data=iris )
text <- sprint( summary(reg) )
```

But it shows that `sprint` method is not found. In which package `sprint` method is declared? Thank you in advance for help.

Comment: Use `capture.output` or `sink`. (There is an `sprintf` function but it won't do what you want.) If you did any searching you should have put in the failed search terms. I found the duplicate just with the first 4 words of the title of your question as the strategy.

Comment: Thank you, capture.output works fine.